If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, show it is integrable on $[c,d]$ where $[c,d] \subseteq [a,b]$.
If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, show it is integrable on $[c,d]$ where $[c,d] \subseteq [a,b]$. I'm not sure if I should prove this directly or by contradiction. If by contradiction, I'm guessing I start by assuming that there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that for all partitions $P$ of $[c,d]$, $U(f,P)-L(f,P) \geq \epsilon$. Then I show that this inequality also holds for all partitions $P'$ of $[a,b]$ via some refinement property. But I'm not sure how to go about this, because $P'$ may not be a refinement of $P$.
I don't need a full answer, because I want to try this myself, but I would appreciate a hint.
Note: I can only use the $U(f,P)-L(f,P)< \epsilon$ criterion.

Proof are available on this  site and there must be a proof in your text book too.

I did find this question elsewhere, but the solutions provided use topics I haven't gotten to yet.

Use Lebesgue's criterion. If you want to see an elementary proof of  Lebesgue's theorem, look up volume 2 of Zorich's Mathematical Analysis

@Asigan Lebesgue's criterion is often not taught in a basic calculus course (I saw it for the first time while studying multivariate calculus), and I believe OP has to prove this with tools he already knows.

Try this: For any partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ add (if necessary) two points $c,d$ to get a new partition $P'$ of $[a,b]$.  show $U(f,P')-L(f,P') \le U(f,P)-L(f,P)$.

What course are you in?  Real analysis?  If Real Analysis, which semester?  I'm guessing you're past Calculus, but wouldn't guarantee it.
Are you studying Riemann integrable functions or have you covered Lebesgue integrable functions yet?  Please don't make us guess your context.

Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Will do, thanks.
